# Automatically disable and enable wireless adapter when connection is lost

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, usb, adapter, wifi-driver

A Compact Wireless-G USB Adapter (USB Wireless receiver) tends to disconnect after 3 hour or so from the internet, when that happens the router is no longer detected, and **with a simple disable/enable** in the "Adapter Settings" Panel the internet comes back to life.

Is there a way to tell Windows 8 to do that automatically when I'm away from my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: look up "devcon" which can enable disable devices, it will take some time to learn how to find and control your device, then make simple batch and have it run out of the scheduler every 2 hours.  It really cannot be done for you easily, because things will have to be tweaked to get it perfect, but I am betting you can do it and post your own answer.  get devcon and play with it in the cmd prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! How about waiting for the next disconnection and look into driver events and use the logged error to tell the task manager to disable/enable the device once the error occurs? I have't used the Task Manager yet, so I have no idea if this can be achieved by it.

Comment: That would work, if the "Event Log" will show a specific error for the specific device at the time of it failing. (look there first) Then the "Task Scheduler" can kick things off based on an "event".  Here one of my nics (intel) keeps tossing up an event everytime the screen goes blank, weird thing of its power management, so as usual it would be more tweaks.  Before getting to deep, check what event would be used to trigger it, and make sure it only does that event when needed.  And make a simple batch that will disable and enable and test that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wireless modems are auatomatically disabled when the windows is in Idle mode(stand-by) so you can disable this behaviour by going to

1. **Control Panel**
2. **Power Options**
3. **select your enabled power plan and select Change Plan settings**
4. **Change Advanced settings**
5. **Set you wireless adapter settings to your preferred option**
6. **Set USB suspend settings to be disabled.**

This will not disconnect your wireless adapter to disconnect from your computer.